# Quickly calculating the 'dirtied' areas between two similar images

Tags: c#, .net, image-processing

I have two very similar images (specifically, two screenshots) and I'm trying to find the best (quickest) way of finding which areas of the image have changed (as an array of rectangles representing the differing areas)

A few criteria:

- It does not need to be pixel-accurate but must include all changes however small (i.e. it would be acceptable for a single-pixel change to have a large margin of error around it)
- It needs to be fast (Ideally 2x 1920x1080 images should take < 20ms on a typical consumer machine purchased today)
- It does not require a configurable threshold (but if there is a solution that allows for this, it would be a nice bonus)
- It can be assumed that the input images are always perfect loss-less images.

I have two working solutions as is but one is a brute force pixel-by-pixel calculation which of course is very slow. And for the other I tried splitting up the two images into chunks of varying sizes and calculating checksums for each chunk, but this is also quite slow.

Just for those wondering what I'm building - it's a kind of dumber (and slower) remote desktop that can be used in a browser without any plugins.

Comment: OpenCV is a nice library to do image processing. That said, if you don't insist on programming something yourself, I found http://www.addictivetips.com/windows-tips/thinvnc-windows-remote-desktop-via-html5-web-browser/ which seems to do s.th similar.

Comment: I'm happy to use an external library, but it needs good C# bindings that are non-GPL (LGPL,BSD,Apache licences are fine - just not a 'viral' licence) and some documentation on features that'd be useful to help me implement this.

Comment: You have to compare every pixel between images - there's no way to get round that. How are you currently doing comparisons? Are you already using unmanaged code?

Comment: I'm not using any unmanaged or unsafe code as it stands. Just a comparison with GetPixel(). I'd prefer to keep purely within managed code if at all possible (but using existing unmanaged libraries with a managed wrapper is fine so long as the wrapper also compiles in Mono)

Comment: A lot of calls to GetPixel are slow. You should use lockbits/unlockbits to make it much faster ([link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5ey6h79d.aspx))

Comment: Yep `GetPixel()` is very slow. Use `LockBits`: [example here](http://www.bobpowell.net/lockingbits.htm). You will have to get your hands dirty with unmanaged memory and pointers, but it's not that hard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to do a pixel per pixel comparison. I don't think it should be that slow. For example the code:

```
        int size = 1920 * 1080 * 3;
        byte[] image1 = new byte[size];
        byte[] image2 = new byte[size];
        byte[] diff = new byte[size];

        var sw = new System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch();
        sw.Start();
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
            diff[i] = (byte) (image1[i] - image1[i]);
        }
        sw.Stop();       
        Console.WriteLine(sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
```

runs in about 40 ms on my laptop. If it's only grayscale, it runs under 20 ms. If you would use real image data the *diff[i] != 0* would indicate a change in the two images.

Your solution might be slow if you are reading the pixel values using *Bitmap.GetPixel* or another slow method. If that is the case I suggest looking up on the *Bitmap.LockBits* or using an unsafe method.

Comment: How about turning the sparse array of differences into an array of rectangles detailing the modified areas? Or should I just stick to doing it in fixed 'regions' for that?

Comment: You could for example use some kind of flood fill on the diff array to get the bounding area of regions with continous change. (Fill regions where the values differs from 0). This would ofc add more processing time.

Comment: Another approach could be to generate a new image where you set the alpha channel transparent where the diff array is zero, and otherwise set a slightly transparent color where the diff array is greater than 0. Then you could draw this image on top of one of the input images.

Comment: Only problem with this is that a 1920x1080 fully-transparent image with a square in the middle is significantly larger in file size than just a square the same size on its own. Keeping the sizes down is a concern.

Comment: You could store the difference mask as a binary image (1-bit per pixel) where  [0 = transparent, 1 = mask], and generate the full-transparent image only in memory after loading it.

Answer (score 3):

My previous answer was deleted because of its format, i will write it again, in a better way.

I was asking you if you consider to use GPU to compute the image differences between your two images. This solution could enhance considerably your computation time as GPU is highly parallel compared to CPU computation.

Using C#, you could try to use XNA for this purpose. Actually i did a little test using a single pass HLSL (it's what is used to program GPU with direct3D) pixel shader :

```
texture texture1;
texture texture2;

sampler textureSampler1 = sampler_state{
    Texture = <texture1>;
};

sampler textureSampler2 = sampler_state{
    Texture = <texture2>;
};

float4 pixelShaderFunction(float2 TextureCoordinate : TEXCOORD0) : COLOR0{
    float4 color1 = tex2D(textureSampler1,TextureCoordinate);
    float4 color2 = tex2D(textureSampler2,TextureCoordinate);
    if((color1.r == color2.r) && (color1.g == color2.g) && (color1.b == color2.b)){
        color1.r = 0;
        color1.g = 0;
        color1.b = 0;
    }
    else{
        color1.r = 255;
        color1.g = 255;
        color1.b = 255;
    }

    return color1;
}


technique Compare
{
    pass Pass1
    {
        PixelShader = compile ps_2_0 pixelShaderFunction();
    }
}
```

The computation on the XNA part is really simple. Using the base snippet of XNA with visual studio, i just wrote the draw function as :

```
protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime) {
   Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
   sw.Start();
   GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.CornflowerBlue);
   e.Parameters["texture1"].SetValue(im1);
   e.Parameters["texture2"].SetValue(im2);
   spriteBatch.Begin(SpriteSortMode.Immediate, BlendState.AlphaBlend, SamplerState.LinearClamp, DepthStencilState.Default, RasterizerState.CullNone, e);
   spriteBatch.Draw(im1,new Vector2(0,0),Color.White);
   spriteBatch.End();
   base.Draw(gameTime);
   sw.Stop();
   Console.WriteLine(sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
}
```

im1 and im2 are the two 1920*1080 colored bmp images loaded as Texture2D, and e is the file.fx loaded as an effect.

Using this technique, i get a 17/18ms computation time on pretty regular computer (laptop with I5-2410m @ 2.3Ghz, 4Gb ram, Nvidia Geforce GT525m.

Here is the output of the program, with the difference image shown (sorry this is highly zoomed because i do NOT have a 1920*1080 screen :>), and besides are the two images im1 and im2 with some little differences between them :
http://img526.imageshack.us/img526/2345/computationtime.jpg

I am pretty new to GPU programming, so if i made a huge mistake regarding how time should be computed or anything else, please feel free to tell !

Edit : 1st thing to note, i just read that "it will be a nontrivial operation as GPUs don't handle branching very well.".

Best regards